# OnItemClickListener and OnItemLongClickListener in ListView

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener, onitemlongclicklistener

I have a problem in a ListView with OnItemClickListener and OnItemLongClickListener. I use both as whays to go to diferent activities. Longclick opens activity for edit that item and (short) click open sub itens activity.  The problem is that when user long click on a ListView item it start the right destination activity but if release just after destination activity is opened my app opens the destination activity for short click as if OnItemClickListener is still active.
This is my code:

```
private void populateAvaliacoesListView(final long periodoId, final int selectedAvaliacoesOpen) {

    ListAdapter adapter = new AvaliacoesListAdapter(this, R.layout._lst_avaliacoes_layout, allAvaliacoes);
    Avaliacoes_lstAvaliacoes.setAdapter(adapter);

    Avaliacoes_lstAvaliacoes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Subitem_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

    });

    Avaliacoes_lstAvaliacoes.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Edit_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

            return false;
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Yes, as simple as that. Thank you.